# Implementing rules on functions in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Suppose you have the following expression:

`expr = f[p^(3) * q^(5) * m] * f[p^(-2) * q^(-5) * m] * f[p^(1/2) * q^(1) * m] +  5 * f[p^(1) * q^(2) * n] * f[q^(-2) * n] + s * f[p^(h) * q^(r) * j] * f[p^(1-h) * q^(-r) * j]`.

Moreover, suppose that the function `f` is such that

`f[p^(a) * q^(b) * x] * f[p^(1-a) * q^(-b) * x] == 1`

for any value (numerical or symbolic) of the exponents `a,b` and for any `x`.
This means that

`expr == f[p^(1/2) * q^(1) * m] + 5 + s`.

How can I teach Mathematica to recognise this property of `f` and then simplify `expr` according to it?

I tried to implement it as the following rule

`/.f[p^(a_)*q^(b_)*x_]f[p^(1-a_)*q^(-b_)*x_]->1`

but it doesn't work. It only works if you specify the numerical value of the exponents `a` and `b`, but not if you want them to be generic.

What is the right way to write such a rule?

Answer (score 0):

The answer here may provide a solution : [How to insert a subexpression into a larger expression in Mathematica?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21290813/how-to-insert-a-subexpression-into-a-larger-expression-in-mathematica/21296154#21296154) c/o Rojo

For example, using your expression `expr` and a larger expression `A`

```
expr = f[p^(a)*q^(b)*x] f[p^(1 - a)*q^(-b)*x];
A = 3 expr + z (f[p^(a)*q^(b)*x]) + y expr

doThat[expr_, vars_List] := Expand[Simplify[expr /. Flatten[
       Solve[# == ToString@#, First@Variables@#] & /@ vars]], 
    Alternatives @@ ToString /@ vars] /.
   Thread[ToString /@ vars -> vars];

done = doThat[A, {expr}];
ans = Simplify[done //. expr -> 1]
```

> 3 + y + z f[p^a q^b x]

The expected answer.

For general cases as per the comment, a pattern can be used, e.g.

```
expr = f[p^(a)*q^(b)*x] f[p^(1 - a)*q^(-b)*x];
A = 3 expr + z (f[p^(a)*q^(b)*x]) +
  y f[p^(h)*q^(l)*x] f[p^(1 - h)*q^(-l)*x];

done = doThat[A, {expr}];
ans = Simplify[done //.
   f[p^(a_)*q^(b_)*x] f[p^(1 - a_)*q^(-b_)*x] -> 1]
```

> 3 + y + z f[p^a q^b x]

But in the end it can simply be done by

```
A /. f[p^(a_)*q^(b_)*x] f[p^(1 - a_)*q^(-b_)*x] -> 1
```

> 3 + y + z f[p^a q^b x]

***2nd edit***

```
A = (3 f[p^(a)*q^(b)*x] f[p^(1 - a)*q^(-b)*x] +
   z (f[p^(a)*q^(b)*x]) +
   y f[p^(h)*q^(l)*x] f[p^(1 - h)*q^(-l)*x] f[p m])

A /. h -> 2 /. f[p^(a_)*q^(b_)*x_] f[p^(1 - a_)*q^(-b_)*x_] -> 1
```

> 3 + z f[p^a q^b x] + y f[m p] f[(q^-l x)/p] f[p^2 q^l x]

When h is 2 the second replacement no longer applies to the expression containing `p^(1 - h)` because the form has become `p^(-1)`.

On the other hand, keeping the variables symbolic by using `Z` instead of 2

```
A /. h -> Z /. f[p^(a_)*q^(b_)*x_] f[p^(1 - a_)*q^(-b_)*x_] -> 1
```

> 3 + y f[m p] + z f[p^a q^b x]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Actually I am not convinced it works. Indeed, if you use for example `A = 3 expr + z (f[p^(a)*q^(b)*x]) + 
  y f[p^(h)*q^(l)*x] f[p^(1 - h)*q^(-l)*x]`, which should give the same answer you got, the output is `3 + z f[p^a q^b x] + y f[p^(1 - h) q^-l x] f[p^h q^l x]`.

Comment: Ok, looks like you can just use the pattern anyway.

Comment: It still does not work properly.
If you want to apply such a routine to a specific expression, whose exponents are numbers, mathematica  will not recognise the pattern 
`f[p^(a_)*q^(b_)*x_] f[p^(1 - a_)*q^(-b_)*x_] -> 1`.
For example, take 
`A = (3 f[p^(a)*q^(b)*x] f[p^(1 - a)*q^(-b)*x] + z (f[p^(a)*q^(b)*x]) + 
    y f[p^(h)*q^(l)*x] f[p^(1 - h)*q^(-l)*x] f[p m]) /. h -> 2`.
The routine output will then be
`3 + y f[m p] f[(m q^-l)/p] f[m p^2 q^l] + z f[p^a q^b x]`.
Clearly mathematica is not applying the general rule to specific cases.
This is precisely where my question originated.

Comment: I used your new example - see 2nd edit. It seems to work.

Comment: My example set `h` to a specific value, i.e. 2. You instead set `expr` to be 2, which is not different from what we discussed before.

Comment: I will try to better explain what I need: given an expression `A` containing sums and products of the function `f`, I want Mathematica to recognise every time there is a combination of the type `f[p^(a_)*q^(b_)*x_] f[p^(1 - a_)*q^(-b_)*x_]` and set it to be 1. Inside `A` the function `f` can appear with numerical exponents for `p,q,...`, so Mathematica has to set `f[p^(a_)*q^(b_)*x_] f[p^(1 - a_)*q^(-b_)*x_]->1` whenever the specific numerical exponents `a,b` satisfy this generic relation.

Comment: I have edited my 2nd edit to show the effect of `h -> 2`.

Comment: Clearly I did not explain well what I needed.
I will edit my question.
Hopefully it will be clearer.